# Differentiating with coefficients

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am stuck on differentiating the following as I am not sure what to do with the coefficient of the cosine:

$$\frac{3\cos(\ln(x^{3}))}{x}$$

My thought would be to use the **chain rule** for the cosine but I am not sure how to do it with the coefficient.

Comment: You can differentiate cosines and logs but you don't  know the product rule?

Comment: Right, perhaps i could use the chain rule to differentiate the cosine first. Then use product rule to differentiate the whole equation

Comment: You can also use the quotient rule.

Comment: In general, as derivatives come from limits:  $\dfrac{d}{dx} kf(x)=k\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{3\cos(\ln(x^3))}{x}&=3\ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\cos(\ln(x^3))}{x} \\
&=3\bigg(\frac{(-\sin(\ln(x^3))\cdot\frac{1}{x^3}\cdot3x^2\cdot x)-(1\cdot\cos(\ln(x^3))}{(x)^2}\bigg) \qquad\textrm{(quotient rule)}\\
&=3\bigg(\frac{-3\sin(\ln(x^3))-\cos(\ln(x^3))}{x^2}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{-9\sin(\ln(x^3))-3\cos(\ln(x^3))}{x^2}
\end{align}